# Scatterplot matrix - Error: Viewport 'plot_01.panel.1.1.off.vp' was not found"

Tags: r, lattice

When I want to create a scatterplot matrix, there is a error about

> Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_downviewport, name$name, strict) : 
>     Viewport 'plot_01.panel.1.1.off.vp' was not found".

How I can fix it?

```
varNum <- function(x){
   val <- 1:ncol(x)
   names(val) <- colnames(x)
   return(val)
}

varNum(house)
     Bedroom   SquareFeet    Followers VisitingTime   TotalPrice    UnitPrice 
           1            2            3            4            5            6 
    District     Location 
           7            8 

house1 <- house[,c(7,1:6)]
offDiag <- function(x,y,...){
   panel.grid(h = -1,v = -1,...)
   panel.hexbinplot(x,y,xbins = 15,...,border = gray(.7),
                    trans = function(x)x^.5)
   #  panel.loess(x , y, ..., lwd=2,col='red')
 }

onDiag <- function(x, ...){
   yrng <- current.panel.limits()$ylim
   d <- density(x, na.rm = TRUE)
   d$y <- with(d, yrng[1] + 0.95 * diff(yrng) * y / max(y) )
   panel.lines(d,col = rgb(.83,.66,1),lwd = 2)
   diag.panel.splom(x, ...)
 }

splom(house1,as.matrix = TRUE,
      xlab = '',main = "Beijing Housing Variables",
      pscale = 0, varname.cex = 0.8,axis.text.cex = 0.6,
      axis.text.col = "purple",axis.text.font = 2,
      axis.line.tck = .5,
      panel = offDiag,
      diag.panel = onDiag
)
```

> Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_downviewport, name$name, strict) : 
>     Viewport 'plot_01.panel.1.1.off.vp' was not found

Answer (score 12):

Try installing the ellipse package. You do not need to load it as a library, only install it.

```
install.packages("ellipse")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case this was caused by specifying the `splom` argument `col = mydataframe$somevariable` which was a categorical variable of strings. Specifying it as `col = as.numeric(as.factor(mydataframe$somevariable))` fixed the issue. To anyone faced with this error message in the future: try removing optional arguments to identfy what might be wrong.